# Jenkins groovy script to get triggered build number

Tags: groovy, jenkins

I'm trying to write down a script that will get the Build Number of a Build that has been triggered by another job. For example:
I have a build job that calls two other jobs(Call/trigger builds on other project). When the main job is finished with success I would like to get the number of the first build job that was triggered from within. The script I'm trying to run founds the main job, however I can't get in any way the build number of the triggered job.

```
 def job = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getItem("Hourly")
job.builds.each {
def build = it
if (it.getResult().toString().equals("SUCCESS")) {The rest of the code should go here!}
```

I was trying to find it in the Jenkins java-doc API and online, however without any luck. Can somebody please help me with that?

P.S. The script runs after the job has finished(triggered when needed only).

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the build number (of the child job) from the build log (of the parent job).
For example:

```
j = Jenkins.getInstance();
jobName = "parentJobName";
job = j.getItem(jobName);
bld = job.getBuildByNumber(parentBuildNumber);

def buildLog = bld.getLog(10); //make sure you read enough lines
def group = (buildLog =~ /#(\d+) of Job : childJobName with/ );
println("The triggered build number: ${group[0][1]}");
```